# Assigning Drive letter for CD-Drive

Tags: cd-drive

I recently bought a CD which needs to run an installation file to run the program. But the anti-piracy system in the CD detects the disc as a virtual or counterfiet disc because Ubuntu does not assign an actual drive letter to the CD-Drive. Is there a way to force ubuntu to assign a drive letter or is there anyother way to work around this problem.

Comment: Linux does not use drive letters.  What are you trying to install?

Comment: Linux does not use drive letters for mounting drives. What are you trying to install? something that requires Wine? More details are needed here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Though Wine didn't work, I managed to install a Windows instance using VirtualBox and opened the CD through the Windows session and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Open wine configuration (winecfg) and go to the Drives tab.

If your cdrom mount point is not present in the list of drives, then add it.
from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=619250)

Added image:
[image]

Your disc is probably at `/media/cdrom` or similar.

Comment: I bought a online Driving theory test CD and am trying to install it. Every time i try start the installation I get a message telling counterfiet/virtual DVD detected. I tried contacting the seller and they said the message is because there is no drive letter assigned to the CD-rom drive. I tried assigning the drive letter using wine as suggested with no luck. Is there any other way??

Comment: They're telling you something incorrect.  There is some other copy-protection problem.